# Guest Entries plugin with Paypal integration?

Tags: guest-entries

I was wondering if someone with Paypal/PHP experience could give some suggestions on how to integrate Paypal with the Guest Entries plugin...

I want to use the Guest Entries plugin to build a job listing (it has been done before, check it out http://pasesetter.org/jobs) and would have to charge a small fee for users (no registration required) to submit job listings.

Before the entry/listing becomes published, users would be redirected directly to PayPal where they can make the payment. Paypal already has an auto-return option for websites payments, so users are redirected back to the site after payment.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Hope that its not too late. I would not use paypal. Use stripe instead. You can then redirect the user to the Charge plugin by Squarebit.co.uk after the entry has posted. Once payment is made, change the status of your entry to enabled. Much cleaner and stripe is easier to work with.

Comment: Hi David! I'd love to use Stripe (I dislike Paypal too). But unfortunately Stripe isn't available in my country yet...